# Where to find documentation on android API repository and Android sdklibs repository?

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I'm going through a code base which uses SDK tools and Android api calls. For example, the code uses the following 2 files:

com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler 
com.android.repository.api.ConsoleProgressIndicator

I need to know more about these 2 classes, but all I have is the jar file that holds these classes. Is there any official google documentation for these? Where can I find them?

Answer (score 0):

You can find Android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages)

If there is no info there, maybe those packages are not official. Just some views or classes Google made for their own purposes or examples.

For example; `ConsoleProgressIndicator` code [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/adt-tools-base/blob/e5faa7ab0f000cee3de4673250585d277c6ec929/repository/src/main/java/com/android/repository/api/ConsoleProgressIndicator.java)

As you can see, it's not a class included in Androids libraries.